# MS Access 2010 throwing "Query Too Complex" error with larger record set

Tags: sql, ms-access, sharepoint, resources

I've having repeated but sporadic issues with Access 2010 throwing up "Query Too Complex" errors on queries that actually aren't hugely complex, but involve a decent number of records (say more than 5000). This always involves working with a linked SharePoint list.

Here's an example (the table I'm inserting into is on the SharePoint server, the other tables are local in the Access file on my drive):

```
INSERT INTO [NR Info] 


(Title, 
    [NR ID], 
    [Project], 
    [Sub-project], 
    [PD Number], 
    [WBS Number], 
    [Network], 
    [IA PO Activity], 
    [FA PO Activity], 
    [ASP], 
    [status], 
    [MS10],
    [PO Status], 
    [2G/3G HW CPO], 
    [4G HW CPO], 
    [4G SW CPO], 
    [Additional HW CPO], 
    [Antenna HW CPO], 
    [2G/3G/4G HWAC CPO], 
    [Swap Prep CPO], 
    [VOD I&C CPO], 
    [Antenna Refresh CPO], 
    [Additional Services CPO], 
    [Decom CPO], 
    [Variances Build Services CPO], 
    [Unknown Variances CPO], 
    [Other CPO A], 
    [Other CPO B], 
    [Other CPO C], 
    [Other CPO D], 
    [Other CPO E] )
SELECT sh.[NR_Unique_ID], 
    sh.[NR_ID], 
    sh.[Project_lookup], 
    sh.[SubProject_lookup], 
    cn.[project_definition], 
    cn.[wbs_element], 
    cn.[network], 
    cpo.[IAPO_activity], 
    cpo.[FAPO_activity], 
    sh.[ASP_lookup], 
    sh.[Status], 
    cpo.[MS10],
    cpo.[cpo_state], 
    cpo.[2G3G_HW_State], 
    cpo.[4G_HW_State], 
    cpo.[4G_SW_State], 
    cpo.[Addl_HW_State], 
    cpo.[Antenna_HW_State], 
    cpo.[2G3G4G_HWACS_State], 
    cpo.[Swap_Prep_State], 
    cpo.[VOD_IC_State], 
    cpo.[Antenna_Refresh_State], 
    cpo.[Addl_Serv_State], 
    cpo.[Decom_State], 
    cpo.[Var_Build_State], 
    cpo.[Unknown_Var_State], 
    cpo.[Other_POA_State], 
    cpo.[Other_POB_State], 
    cpo.[Other_POC_State], 
    cpo.[Other_POD_State], 
    cpo.[Other_POE_State]
FROM (Staging_SH_keyData AS sh 
    LEFT JOIN Staging_SAP_CN AS cn ON sh.[NR_ID] = cn.[nr_id]) 
    LEFT JOIN staging_SH_cpoStatus AS cpo ON sh.[NR_Unique_ID] = cpo.[NR_Unique_ID]
WHERE sh.[NR_Unique_ID] NOT IN (SELECT [title] FROM [NR Info]);
```

This would be another one which also causes issues when working on big record sets. I tried to use it to insert about 13,000 rows from my local file to the Sharepoint server. I ended up having to use a TOP 1000 temporarily on the SELECT and run the query 13+ times. Even then, I'd periodically get the error, though closing the file and re-opening it would fix it for a few more runs. I'd also sometimes get "System Resource" related issues.

```
INSERT INTO [Order Items]
    ([Title], 
        [Order Item],
        [NR ID],
        [Vfe Material ID], 
        [E/// Material Num], 
        [Material Description], 
        [Item Category], 
        [Quantity Ordered], 
        [Date Requested], 
        [Requester], 
        [Item Request Status], 
        [PO2 Number], 
        [PO2 Line Number], 
        [PO Technical Check], 
        [PO Accepted Date], 
        [SO Number], 
        [SO Line Number], 
        [SO Line Status], 
        [SO Item Quantity], 
        [SO Release Date], 
        [SO Activated Date], 
        [Event Day], 
        [MS10])
SELECT [Order_Item], 
    [Order_Item],
    (SELECT TOP 1 [id] FROM [NR Info] nri WHERE nri.[NR ID]=soi.[NR_ID]),
    [VF_SAP_Material], 
    [Mat_Num], 
    [Mat_Desc], 
    [Mat_Cat], 
    [Order_Quan], 
    [Request_Date], 
    [Requester], 
    [Item_ReqStatus], 
    [PO2_Num], 
    [PO2_LineNum], 
    [PO_TechCheck], 
    [PO_AcceptedDate], 
    [SO_Num], 
    [SO_LineNum], 
    [SO_LineStatus], 
    [SO_Quantity], 
    [SO_RelDate], 
    [SO_ActivatedDate], 
    [EventDay], 
    [MS10]
FROM Staging_OrderItems AS soi
WHERE soi.[Order_Item] NOT IN (SELECT [Title] FROM [Order Items]);
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As per [this article](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-02.html):

JET gives this generic message any time it cannot pinpoint what's wrong. The cause can be wrong delimiters, misinterpreted data types, mismatched brackets, using reserved words as table or field names or aliases, confusion from Name AutoCorrect, or a host of other possibilities.

#### Solutions

In most cases, the solution it to figure out which part Access does not understand. Check the data types match in expressions, joins, and criteria. Explicitly typecast where needed. Explicitly declare parameters, so JET knows their type.

Verify your names (tables, fields, aliases) are not on the reserved words list. Add square brackets around any suspect names, and explicitly specify their source table, e.g. "SELECT [Table1].[Name] FROM ... " rather than "SELECT Name FROM ... "

Make sure Name AutoCorrect is off. Then compact/repair the database.

If necessary, break the query down to find the problem. Drop half of the WHERE clause, omit the GROUP BY clause until the query works. Then start adding thing back until you pinpoint the culprit.

Occasionally, the query actually is too complex: too many UNIONs, more than 32 tables, 100 ANDs in the WHERE clause, or nesting queries more than 50 levels deep. For a list of the limits, open Help in the main Access window, and enter specifications. In Access 2007, go to help topic HA10030739.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can pinpoint anything based on those ideas, and will add some explicit type casting, etc. But I'm not sure it's the query itself, rather oddly. The reason I say that is because it seems to depend on how many rows are being inserted. For example, when I wanted to put in 13000+ rows, it gave the error. But when I ran the same query 13+ times with a SELECT TOP 1000 in there, I never had an issue. It ONLY seems to occur when I do a large-ish insert.

Comment: Well, in the similar situation we have been forced to migrate to SQL Express and use Access Data Project as frontend. This happened just because the number of random problems we have had with the pure mdb projects.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I could do that. I've worked with SQL Server (regular and Express) enough to really miss the features, speed and stability compared to Access. Sadly, Access and Sharepoint are the tools I've got to work with.